# URI for skype for business, sip:username is not working in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, lync, skype-for-business

I want to open window for skype for business (or Lync). In appcelerator i am trying by following :

```
Ti.platform.openURL("sip:username");
```

But it's only open skype for business App. (Not window of user, that username i have provided).

what I want to do is open window of user directly for chat? Also if there is group for chat I want to create chat group?

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-uris/sfbmobileuri

Comment: Awesome link, Thanks developer82.

Comment: I just wondering that how can we create group
using : ["ms-sfb://chat?id=user@contoso.com"] this I am able to open the chat window for individual user.

I have tried  ["ms-sfb://chat?id=user@contoso.com;user2@contoso.com;user3@contoso.com&topic=chatgroup"]
But no luck.

Is there any help on it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to open user window in my app. Here is the code I have used.

```
ms-sfb://chat?id=user@contoso.com
```

It works for me.